# Unable to add link in the Summary Links web part by power shell script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, script, powershell

I want to add links to the summary link web part using the power shell script. I have found a script for it on [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Update-Summary-Link-Field-fb11fb6d) link, but is it not working as per the requirement.

I have a publishing website and the default.aspx already has this web part placed on it. When I run the script, I can see the new links neing added to the property of the page instead of the user interface. I don't know what is wrong with this.

Please guide me  asap.